# How to reverse a linked list using an STL stack?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl, stack, reverse

I tried searching for a solution from the Internet but I couldn't find one.

Is it possible to reverse a linked list using `std::stack<Node* temp>`?  If so, how?

Comment: Why not reverse it directly and efficiently?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a site for people to teach you how to program.   Give it a shot and if your code doesn't work, post the code and the exact problem you're having and someone can tell you how to fix it.  Also, be specific about a single question - you appear to be asking for code on how to do it as well a whether a stack can be used.   What are you actually asking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no attempt at solving the problem demonstrated

Answer (score 3):

It certainly *is* possible with a stack. The *algorithm* for such a beast (since this is probably class work) is really quite simple when you realise that you *pop* elements off a stack in the reverse order that you pushed them on.

So, something like this is what you're looking for:

```
def reverseList (List<Type> &list):
    Stack<Type> stack
    while not list.empty():                   # 1 2 3 ... 9
        stack.push(list.getAndRemoveFirst())
    while not stack.empty():                  # 9 8 7 ... 1
        list.pushBack(stack.pop())
```

---

But keep in mind that, if you're doing this in a "real" situation (not class work), `std::list` actually *has* the facility to reverse lists:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <list>
using std::list;

int main () {
    list<int> lst;

    for (int val: {9, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3})
        lst.push_back(val);

    cout << "Original list:";
    for (const auto &item: lst)
        cout << ' ' << item;
    cout << '\n';

    lst.reverse();

    cout << "Reversed list:";
    for (const auto &item: lst)
        cout << ' ' << item;
    cout << '\n';

    cout << "\nReverse ITERATOR of\nreversed list:";
    for (auto iter = lst.crbegin(); iter != lst.crend(); ++iter)
        cout << ' ' << *iter;
    cout << '\n';
}
```

That last section shows how you can *iterate* over the list in reverse order if that's all that you needed the reversal for. It doesn't actually *change* the order of the list but instead just allows you to process the items backwards.

The output of that code is:

```
Original list: 9 5 3 5 6 2 9 5 1 4 1 3
Reversed list: 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 9

Reverse ITERATOR of
reversed list: 9 5 3 5 6 2 9 5 1 4 1 3
```

Comment: Or, if all you want it to enumerate the list in reverse, just use `rbegin()` and `rend()` members and iterate as usual.

Comment: Good point, @WhozCraig, have added that into the answer.